# thanksgiving for helpers in style of abstract

Tags: koma-script, abstract, scrreprt

i'm using `scrreport` and before my document start i put a abstract using usepackage `abstract`:
`\begin{abstract}
\blindtext{}
\end{abstract}`

But now i want to put before the abstract another page which looks the same.

The heading should be change to something like thanksgiving (german: Danksagung).

It's a common thing to say thank you for all the people who helped while writing the document.

I tried to reproduce this page using `\minisec{Danksagung}` but this looks a lot different.

I also searched in the CTAN-documentation for scrreport for a solution.

**Update 20-10-17 15:03** 
The minimum example worked fine. But if i change the babel options to the options i use it stops working. I change it to have the german hyphenation.

```
\documentclass[abstract]{scrreprt}

\usepackage[UKenglish, german]{babel}
%\providecaptionname{german}{\thanksgivingname}{Thanksgiving}
\providecaptionname{ngerman}{\thanksgivingname}{Danksagung}

\newenvironment{thanksgiving}
  {\renewcommand\abstractname{\thanksgivingname}\begin{abstract}}
  {\end{abstract}}

\usepackage{blindtext}% only for dummy text in the example
\begin{document}
\begin{thanksgiving}
\blindtext
\end{thanksgiving}

\begin{abstract}
\blindtext
\end{abstract}
\end{document}
```

**Update 20-10-17 15:35** 
i just used the wrong the wrong caption provide. This works then:

```
\documentclass[abstract]{scrreprt}

\usepackage[UKenglish, german]{babel}
\providecaptionname{german}{\thanksgivingname}{Thanksgiving}
%\providecaptionname{ngerman}{\thanksgivingname}{Danksagung}

\newenvironment{thanksgiving}
  {\renewcommand\abstractname{\thanksgivingname}\begin{abstract}}
  {\end{abstract}}

\usepackage{blindtext}% only for dummy text in the example
\begin{document}
\begin{thanksgiving}
\blindtext
\end{thanksgiving}

\begin{abstract}
\blindtext
\end{abstract}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`scrreprt` provides an environment `abstract` too. To enable a heading for the abstract use class option `abstract` or `abstract=true`.

You can define a new environment `thanksgiving` that bases on environment `abstract`.

```
\documentclass[abstract]{scrreprt}

\usepackage[english]{babel}
\providecaptionname{english}{\thanksgivingname}{Thanksgiving}
\providecaptionname{ngerman}{\thanksgivingname}{Danksagung}

\newenvironment{thanksgiving}
  {\renewcommand\abstractname{\thanksgivingname}\begin{abstract}}
  {\end{abstract}}

\usepackage{blindtext}% only for dummy text in the example
\begin{document}
\begin{thanksgiving}
\blindtext
\end{thanksgiving}

\begin{abstract}
\blindtext
\end{abstract}
\end{document}
```

Result:

[image]

---

You could use a list in the first argument of `\providecaptionname`:

```
\documentclass[abstract]{scrreprt}

\usepackage[UKenglish,german]{babel}
\providecaptionname{english,UKenglish}{\thanksgivingname}{Thanksgiving}
\providecaptionname{ngerman,german}{\thanksgivingname}{Danksagung}

\newenvironment{thanksgiving}
  {\renewcommand\abstractname{\thanksgivingname}\begin{abstract}}
  {\end{abstract}}

\usepackage{blindtext}% only for dummy text in the example
\begin{document}
\begin{thanksgiving}
\blindtext
\end{thanksgiving}

\begin{abstract}
\blindtext
\end{abstract}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you for the really fast answer. I'll try as soon as i find the time :)

Comment: hello esdd i tried your answer but i got a problem (your example works)

Comment: @himynameis See my updated answer. You have to use `\providecaptionname{german}{...}{...}` or `\providecaptionname{ngerman,german}{...}{...}`.

Comment: Thank i just saw it too :)
very nice solution though